# Ruby on rails3 login tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm new to Ruby on rails and followed the Labs of railsforzombies.org and passed all 5 labs. 
I'm looking for good simple help for start to make CMS in rails 3. and at first want to implement simple login page with sessions. 
Any expert here to guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its OK to use a gem for it, Devise is recommended, can be customized and has all the functionality you would need.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

If you want to implement from scratch,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

This railscast looks good, the site has pretty much all you would need about rails, should bookmark.

Comment: I'll add all the railscast episode about Devise : [209, 210, 233, ...](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=devise) or more globally [all episodes about authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=authentication)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find nice tutorial with gem **authlogic** and how to make the Unobtrusive login ( with Ajax ) .

Check it out :
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-build-an-unobtrusive-login-system-in-rails/